# How to display some text for menu in ActionBar?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have simple requirement to **display some text in the actionBar near the menu**. How can I acheive it?

What it looks like now?

[image: actual image]

What I need?

[image: expected outcome]

Answer (score 0):

Try this `ActionBar` menu sample:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  xmlns:yourApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>

    ... ...     

    <item 
      android:id="@+id/item_text"
      yourApp:showAsAction="always"
      yourApp:actionLayout="@layout/action_text"

    />
</menu>
```

Then you need a layout `action_text` for your `TextView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   >

    ... ...    

  <TextView android:id="@+id/lb_text" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:text="@string/your_text"
    android:textSize="10sp"  
    android:textColor="@color/white"  
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:title="Options"
    app:showAsAction="withText|always" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_options_unused"
    app:showAsAction="withText|always"
    android:title="Options"
 />
```

Don't set a `android:icon` if you don't want an icon appearing at the left side of your textual item. Also make sure this `<item>` is the last one in your menu's XML file.